# How to set Nginx for non root location properly?

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I would like to set up Nginx for Flask applications with uWSGI server. I have set the proxy over unix socket as the following.

The initial Nginx configuration:

```
    server {
        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/my_app.sock;
        }
    }
```

The uWSGI configuration:

```
    [uwsgi]
    socket = /tmp/my_app.sock
    virtualenv = /home/user/venv/my_app
    chdir = /home/user/apps/my_app
    wsgi-file = index.py
    callable = app
    processes = 4
    threads = 2
```

This works but when I change the location in the Nginx config I have get a 404 Not Found error.

```
    server {
        location /other_location/ {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/my_app.sock;
        }
    }
```

The error possibly comes from the uWSGI server (because for other invalid URL the error page writes the Nginx version). I have checked the uWSGI log but it contains only the details about sending the error page with success.

```
     => generated 233 bytes in 15 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 72 bytes
```

How can I configure Nginx and uWSGI for working with non root locations?

Is it necessary to set the application route in the source code of the application?

I prefer solutions where I can use the unmodified application code. I like to separate the application development and deployment as possible.